# Data Binding Help - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have those two classes:

```
class DownloadLink
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Url { get; private set; }
    //(...)
}

class DownloadGroup
{        
    public List<DownloadLink> Links { get; private set; }
    //(...)
}

class Manager
{
    public List<DownloadGroup> Groups { get; private set; }
}

Manager managerOBJ = new Manager();
```

I want to display this like that:

Everything will be in ListBox:
I wan to bind managerOBJ.Groups to that ListBox. - How to do it?
Than I want to create DataTamplate to display each group and all links in that group. - How to do it?

I want to do as much as possible from XAML

UPDATE:

This is what I got. It's not workig. List box is empty.

```
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE1FFF5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}" Name="GroupsListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" >
                    <Grid Height="Auto" Width="500">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="XX MB w XX plikach" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="43" Margin="0,5,0,0" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Links}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and in code behid I have:

```
RapideoAccount = new Rapideo();
GroupsListBox.DataContext = RapideoAccount;
```

Comment: Look at the Related questions shown to the right of your question.  You've been asking lots of repetitive questions that are getting closed.  Boring us all to tears, frankly.  You'd better watch out for the feared User Ban Script, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole manager is contained in a listbox, for each downloadgroup in the manager you add an itemscontrol that contains another items control with the links in it. 
This can be done by using DataTemplates:

```
    <ListBox Name="myGroups"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}">
    <!-- each List<DownloadGroup> in the manager: -->
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Links}">
                <!-- each Link in the Downloadgroup -->
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Url}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In code you would put:

```
Manager managerOBJ = new Manager();
myGroups.DataContext = managerOBJ;
```

Comment: What exactly is a Rapideo, is that the Manager you had earlier?

Answer (score 0):

1. define `managerOBJ` as a **property** in your viewmodel
2. binding viewmodel to your view.
3. binding ListBox `itemssource` to `managerOBJ.Groups`.
4. define `DataTemplate` inside ListBox to display each `DownloadGroup`.